# My gridview has 4 columns, and the error says "a table should have at least 1 column"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, itext

This is my gridview

[image]

When I want to convert the gridview this appears

[image]

The output odf has a header and a footer.

FYI: the columns in the gridview are autogenerated (autogeneratecolumns=true)

Comment: What is the value in gvDolarAnual.Columns.Count? The err msg indicates it's less than 1.

Comment: Are you doing this after the databind is called for the grid?  If not, then it could be that the grid just doesn't have anything to load into it yet.

Comment: First i fill the gridview (FillDolarAnual(anioInicio, anioFin, IDMoneda);)
gvDolarAnual.DataSource = DTgvDolarAnual;
gvDolarAnual.DataBind();

Then i try to count the columns
iTextSharp.text.Table tabla_datos = new iTextSharp.text.Table(gvDolarAnual.Columns.Count);